# Modifying the Date.protype

Tags: typescript

If I try this:

```
Date.prototype.add = function (days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
};
```

The ts compiler complains that add doesn't exist for date..

ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to extend the date interface to tell the compiler about your add method:

```
interface Date {
    add (days: number) : Date;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Date.prototype.add = function (days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
};

var date = new Date();

var newDate = date.add(1);
```